# retry the api request when error return in UNcomtrade

Tags: python

To retrieve data from UNcomtrade, I use a loop. However, when the retrieval fails, it returns an error message and breaks the loop. I want to retry retrieving the data if an error occurs.But my code is not work.

Here's an example of the main code and loop structure

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
import os
import comtradeapicall
import json
import csv
from itertools import islice

year='1990'
line=1
max_retries = 10
retry_delay = 5 
directory = '...'
subscription_key =".."
csv_file_path = "...reporter.csv"
combined_df = pd.DataFrame()

print(f"year {year} .")
with open(csv_file_path, "r") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)

    header = next(csv_reader)
    id_index = header.index("id")
    for _ in range(line-1):
        next(csv_reader)
    for row_number, row in enumerate(csv_reader, start=line):
        reporter_code = row[id_index]
        print(f"Row {row_number}: {reporter_code}")
   
        request_success = False
        for retry in range(max_retries):

            try:
               
                mydf = comtradeapicall.getFinalData(subscription_key, typeCode='C', freqCode='A', clCode='SS',
                                                period=year,
                                                reporterCode=reporter_code, cmdCode='AG2', flowCode='X',
                                                partnerCode='0',
                                                partner2Code=None, customsCode=None, motCode=None, maxRecords=250000,
                                                format_output='JSON',
                                                aggregateBy=None, breakdownMode='classic', countOnly=None,
                                                includeDesc=True)
                if mydf is not None:
                    request_success = True
                    break
                
            except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, requests.exceptions.ProxyError) as e:
                print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
                if retry < max_retries - 1:
                    print(f"Retrying in {retry_delay} seconds...")
                    time.sleep(retry_delay)
                else:
                    print("Max retries exceeded. Unable to complete the request.")

        if request_success:        
            df = pd.DataFrame(mydf)
            print(f"get {row_number}: {reporter_code}")
            combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df, df], ignore_index=True)
            print(f"Data for reporterCode {reporter_code} concatenated.")
            time.sleep(10)  # Add a delay of 30 seconds before the next iteration
        else:
             print(f"Skipping row {row_number}: {reporter_code}")
```

Error message return

```
SystemExit: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='comtradeapi.un.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/v1/get/C/A/SS?reportercode=474&flowCode=X&period=1989&cmdCode=AG4&partnerCode=0&maxRecords=250000&format=JSON&breakdownMode=classic&includeDesc=True&subscription-key= (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

Reporter can down from `comtradeapicell`

```
reporter = comtradeapicall.getReference('reporter')
```